# On cardinality: $|[0,1]|\ge|\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}|$ and $|\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}|\ge |(0,1)|$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I have already proved the following results:

> **Proposition 1.** Let $p\in\mathbb{N}$, $p\ge 2$.
>
> Let $x\in [0,1).$ Then exists a sequenece $\{c_k\}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $0\le c_k\le p-1$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $$x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{c_k}{p^k}.$$

$$$$

> **Proposition 2.**
>   Let $p\in\mathbb{N}$, $p\ge2$. Let $x\in[0,1)$ such that 
>   \begin{equation}
> x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{p^k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{b_k}{p^k}
> \end{equation}
>   with two distinct sequences $\{a_k\}$, $\{b_k\}\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, $0\le a_k\le p-1$, $0\le b_k\le p-1$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> Then exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_k=0$, $b_k=p-1$ for all $k\ge n+1$.

---

Let $x\in (0,1)$, then for Proposition 1, in particular,  $$x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{c_k}{2^k}$$ with $\{c_k\}\in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. The map  $$\varphi_2\colon (0,1)\to \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}},\quad\varphi(x):=\{c_k\}$$ defined by choosing binary development with a finite number $c_k\ne 0$ of in ambiguous cases (see Proposition 2.), is injective. In fact let $x,y\in (0,1)$, then exists $\{c_k\},\{d_k\}\in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $$x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{c_k}{2^k}\quad\text{and}\quad y=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{d_k}{2^k}.$$ We suppose that $\varphi_2(x)=\varphi_2(y)$, then $\{c_k\}=\{d_k\}$ this means that $c_k=d_k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore $$x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{c_k}{2^k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{d_k}{2^k}=y,$$ then $\varphi_2$ is injective.

> **Question 1.** It's correct?

Now, we cosider tha map $$\varphi_3\colon \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}\to [0,1],\quad\varphi_3(\{c_k\}):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{c_k}{3^k}$$

> **Question 2** How can I show that $\varphi_3$ to be injective using the above proposition?

$$$$

> **Question 3.** Is $\varphi_3$ onto?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't choose a binary development with finitely many $c_k\not = 0$. (It's like saying that all the numbers are rational).  What would you take instead of the sequence $(1,0,1,0,1,0,...)$?

Comment: In the sense of the above proposition

Comment: Right I see you only choose this binary development if there are two different ways to express $x$. This also explains how $\varphi_2(x)=\varphi_2(y)$ implies that $x=y$ (perhaps you want to say a word about this). Other than that it seems like the answer to Question $1$ is yes. Also the answer to Question 2 is that $\varphi_3$ is not injective because if you take $a_k,b_k$ as in the proposition you will have that $\varphi_3(\{a_k\}) = \varphi_3 (\{b_k\})$.

Comment: I do not understand. Then, in order for $\varphi_2$ to be well definited, if $x$ admits two binary equal developments, by convention, I choose that which is definitively null, by virtue of the previous lemma. For my book $\varphi_3$ is injjective, but I did not understand why.

Comment: Oh right $\varphi_3$ is injective (didn't realized you divide by $3^k$ instead of $2^k$) this follows from the proposition as if two expressions are equal one of the expressions must correspond to a sequence which takes the value $p-1$ in this case $p-1=2$ but we don't get such values. $\varphi_3$ is not onto, it doesn't get $1$ (you can calculate the maximum by choosing all the $c_k$ to be one).